# Need JSON Dumps to give me string without single quotes

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

**The issue was different and was with how expected output was handling the json. Apologies for wasting your time.**

I have a python dictionary object which I'm trying to return in a string format so that another function does a string comparision. I have no control over the other function so it's my responsibility to return in the requested format.

Right now I have this
myfunction(params) which returns (json.dump(dictionary object))

```
'{"Engineering": {"employees": 3, "employees_with_outside_friends": 2}, "HR": {"employees": 1, "employees_with_outside_friends": 1}, "Business": {"employees": 1, "employees_with_outside_friends": 1}, "Directors": {"employees": 1, "employees_with_outside_friends": 0}}'
```

But I want the return to look like regular string which gets printed when i run print(dict)

```
{"Engineering": {"employees": 3, "employees_with_outside_friends": 2}, "HR": {"employees": 1, "employees_with_outside_friends": 1}, "Business": {"employees": 1, "employees_with_outside_friends": 1}, "Directors": {"employees": 1, "employees_with_outside_friends": 0}}
```

Sample Code:

```
def get_actual_output():
    dict_ = dict({"Engineering": {"employees": 3, "employees_with_outside_friends": 2},"HR": {"employees": 1, "employees_with_outside_friends": 1},"Business": {"employees": 1, "employees_with_outside_friends": 1},"Directors": {"employees": 1, "employees_with_outside_friends": 0}})
    return(json.dumps(dict_))

expected_output = '{"Engineering": {"employees": 3, "employees_with_outside_friends": 2},"HR": {"employees": 1, "employees_with_outside_friends": 1},"Business": {"employees": 1, "employees_with_outside_friends": 1},"Directors": {"employees": 1, "employees_with_outside_friends": 0}}'

get_actual_output() == expected_output returns False
```

Adding Some more details :

When I print the return of the above function and the expected values, this is what I get :

```
>>> actual_output
'{"Business": {"employees": 1, "employees_with_outside_friends": 1}, "Dir
ectors": {"employees": 1, "employees_with_outside_friends": 0}, "Engineer
ing": {"employees": 3, "employees_with_outside_friends": 2}, "HR": {"empl
oyees": 1, "employees_with_outside_friends": 1}}'

>>> test['expected_output']
{'Business': {'employees': 1, 'employees_with_outside_friends': 1},
 'Directors': {'employees': 1, 'employees_with_outside_friends': 0},
 'Engineering': {'employees': 3, 'employees_with_outside_friends': 2},
 'HR': {'employees': 1, 'employees_with_outside_friends': 1}}
```

Comment: You can't have both.

Comment: is there a way for json.dumps() to return without single quotes?

Comment: `json.dumps` already returns without single quotes.  It uses double quotes.  Next question?

Comment: `json.dumps` does not return a string with single quotes in it; the single quotes are part of the string's `repr`.

Comment: @user2357112 can you please tell me how i could get rid of that?, I'm at it for a while..

Comment: You're just printing it wrong. Please show a [mcve] of the code

Comment: @cricket_007 How about now?

Comment: Try putting a single after each comma `,` in both the dict and the string.

Comment: You already have a dictionary `dict_ = {"Engineering": {"`... Why are you using `dict()`? Also whitespacing can be different

Comment: @wim tried that. It still returns false

Comment: @cricket_007 i'm actually computing a dictionary in that form. Instead of pasting those details here. I'm just trying to explain here that I have a dictionary of that form which i'm returning through json.dump and on comparing the return string, I'm getting false.

Comment: Are there any booleans in the dictionary?  They look like `False` in python and `false` in json.

Comment: @wim There are no booleans in the dictionary. I shared few more details based on the values printed in python prompt. I'm wondering why those single quotes are there and if that is the reason.

Comment: So, in the new details you've added, the `test['expected_output']` is not a string at all.  It's a dict.

Comment: Yeah, I understand it now. Thanks @wim

Answer (score 1):

Your example with `get_actual_output() == expected_output` doesn't match just because you're missing whitespace before some keys. For example: `...s": 2},"HR": {"em...`, where the actual output is `...s": 2}, "HR": {"em...`. You can't get the format you want out of `json.dumps`, because you have space before some keys, but not other ones.

You can get rid of all the spaces with `json.dumps(..., separators=(',', ': '))`, but that's likely just confusing the situation some more.

Ideally, you should parse the string response and compare that instead. This way, you'll also avoid the issue of the order of the elements not being guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

Json is different from python dictionary representation, when you print a dictionary, python doesn't use json syntax to generate the string representation of the dictionary, dict objects have their own implementation of __str__ which is invoked when calling str or doing a print(which calls str on the object).

str(dict_ ) produces a string that is generated by __str__, and does not follow the json syntax, it is similar, but not the same, these are two different syntaxes.

Also, json only allows double quotes for strings, while python allows for both double and single quotes.

Doing simple processing to the json to make it look like a python repr of a dict (like removing/replacing quotes..) is a bad idea, you will have issues when dealing with complex objects representation or even floats.

if you want a string that looks like the string generated by printing the dict, use str(dict_ ).